# Advanced URL Parameters

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to neaten my urls. I have a mod_rewrite that findes files ending with '.php?slug=[some+text]' and replaces with '/[some+text]'. However that does not enable you to store more than one variable in a url without it looking messy.

I have tried to write a php script that takes a url looking like:

```
.php?slug=search/this+is+a+search/tags/php+sql/page/2
```

which should replace it with

```
array(
   'search'->'this is a search',
   'tags'->'php sql',
   'page'->2
);
```

I have got this far.

```
if(isset($_GET['slug'])&&$_GET['slug']!=''){
$url=$_GET['slug'];
$params=explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$url);
print_r($params);
}
```

This returns:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => search
  [1] => this is a search
  [2] => tags 
  [3] => php sql 
  [4] => page 
  [5] => 2 
)
```

How can I convert that to the array at the top? Is there a better way to do this?

One way I found after playing aroud was:

```
if(isset($_GET['slug'])&&$_GET['slug']!=''){
    $url=$_GET['slug'];
    $params=explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$url);
    $out=array();
    $array_size = count($params);
    for($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i+=2)
    {
        $key=$params[$i];
        $value=$params[$i+1];
        $out[$key]=$value;
    }
    print_r($out);

}
```

This sort of works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$params = array_combine(array_map(function($a) {return $a[0];},$tmp = array_chunk($params,2)),array_map(function($a) {return $a[1];},$tmp));
```

One-liner!

Note that you're not actually achieving anything. Compare:

```
somefile.php?search=some+text&tags=php+sel&page=2
somefile/search/some+text/tags/php+sel/page/2
```

Aside from removing the extension, you're not gaining anything. You're just making it harder on yourself by needing to parse a complicated string.

Comment: I agree, the page should be a GET variable and the rest can be part of the URL. `somefile/search/some+text?tags=php+sel&page=2`

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do all the work with the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$    index.php?search=$1    [QSA]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$    index.php?search=$1&tags=$2    [QSA]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?search=$1&tags=$2&page=$3    [QSA]
```

Then all you would have to do is access each one like this:

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['search'];
$tags = $_GET['tags'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
?>
```

Note: the [QSA] means that you can still have messy url variables after the neat ones. This is handy if you want to pass a boolean through or an id but don't mind if it looks messy.

I know this isn't really the question you asked but you might find it easier this way.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if there is only search and page however. The way I was trying to do it meant that you could do it in any order or with any posible mix of the three - so any combination of one or two tags.

Comment: You can do this in any combination but not in any order. Follow the a=other answer if you want to do it that way, but this is the neatest way.

Answer (score 0):

You could break the string on `/` using the first value for the array key.

```
//$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//$url = $_GET['slug'];
$url = 'search/this+is+a+search/tags/php+sql/page/2';

preg_match_all('~([^/]+)/([^/]+)~', $url, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$values = array();
foreach($matches as $match)
{
    $values[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}

print_r($values);
```